# Dungeon ArrayList printing improperly. Game of Zork

Tags: java, constructor

I can't figure this out, my dungeon is printing improperly(question and output at bottom). This is going to be a bit of code, but it's all necessary.

here's the dungeon constructor:

```
public Dungeon ( )
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int determinedDungeonSize = r.nextInt(10-5) + 5;        
        int weaponRandom = r.nextInt(determinedDungeonSize);

        dungeon = new ArrayList<String>(determinedDungeonSize);

        String cell = ("|____|   ");
        char[] cellArray = cell.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0; i<determinedDungeonSize ;i++)
        {
            int randomProbability = r.nextInt(10000);

            if(randomProbability < 5000)
            {
                cellArray[2] = 'M';
            }

            if(i == weaponRandom)
            {
                if(randomProbability < 5000)
                {
                    cellArray[3] = 'S';
                    cellArray[4] = 'w';
                }
                else
                {
                    cellArray[3] = 'S';
                    cellArray[4] = 't';
                }

            }//end if

            cell = String.valueOf(cellArray);
            dungeon.add(cell);
        }//end for

    }//end Dungeon()
```

toString for the Dungeon:

```
public String toString()
{
    String dungeonString = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < dungeon.size(); i++)
    {
        dungeonString += dungeon.get(i);
    }

    return dungeonString;
}
```

Now here's the problem. I'm printing off the dungeon in the driver class with this statement-> `System.out.print(d.toString());`, where d is just a Dungeon object created w/ `Dungeon d = new Dungeon()`
And the console is outputting(Here's a bad case):

```
|_M__|   |_M__|   |_M__|   |_MSt|   |_MSt|   |_MSt|   |_MSt|
```

The probability of a Monster, denoted 'M', being in a cell is 50/50. The probability for a Weapon(Stick('St') or Sword('Sw')) to exist is ONE WEAPON PER DUNGEON(only one weapon in any given dungeon, cell must be random). The constructor should be doing all this just fine, I have no idea what is going wrong here and I have been trying to solve this for 6 hours now.

EDIT: EXPECTED OUTPUT:  |*M*_|  |*M*_|  |**_*|  |*_St_|  |*M***|  |**_|  |*M***| |___|

Comment: Why do you have `if(i == weaponRandom) {` in there? That will make sure that you will not get Sw or St each time. Also, learn to use the debugger, you would not have searched for six hours on this problem then...

Comment: I didn't search for six hours, I didn't have internet. I was trying to just figure it out. `weaponRandom` should just be an int between 0 and the `determinedDungeonSize` which is why I only do it when `i == weaponRandom`. So that, randomly, only one cell gets a Weapon.

Comment: What does "one cell per dungeon" mean? What output do you expect? Also, you don't get another `randomProbability` between monster and weapon... so the number does not change.

Comment: Sorry, I'll clear that up a little bit. What I mean by one cell per dungeon is that - There should only be one weapon, and it should only be in one cell of any given Dungeon.

Comment: What's the expected output ?

Comment: Sorry. EXPECTED OUTPUT(something like this):  |_M__| |_M__| |____| |____| |_MSw| |____|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you never refresh the value of `cellArray` to be a "new" cell at the end of your for loop. You just write on top of the existing cell. This means that if an `M` appears in the very first cell, it will appear in every cell. Furthermore, the weapon will appear in every cell after the first time it appears. To fix this, you need to re-initialize `cell` each time you run the for loop. Just move the initialization to inside the loop:

```
    for(int i=0; i<determinedDungeonSize ;i++)
    {
        //just move these to the inside of the loop
        //so they are fresh each time
        String cell = ("|____|   ");
        char[] cellArray = cell.toCharArray();

        int randomProbability = r.nextInt(10000);

        if(randomProbability < 5000)
        {
            cellArray[2] = 'M';
        }

        if(i == weaponRandom)
        {
            if(randomProbability < 5000)//this does mean that if the weapon is in the same room as a monster, it will always be Sw. Consider generating a new random value
            {
                cellArray[3] = 'S';
                cellArray[4] = 'w';
            }
            else
            {
                cellArray[3] = 'S';
                cellArray[4] = 't';
            }

        }//end if

        cell = String.valueOf(cellArray);
        dungeon.add(cell);
    }//end for
```

Comment: Very nice man. That's it lol.. let me test but.. but I'm sure that's it.